# CSS show/hide next elements

Tags: css

I'd like to hide the second `id` with value `my2` via CSS:

```
<div class="node1">
  <div class="xxx"> blablabla </div>
</div>
<div id="my2">
  <div class="xxx"> blablalbla </div>
</div>
<div class="node2">
  <div class="xxx"> blablabla </div>
</div>
<div id="my2">
  <div class="xxx"> blablalbla </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible as to hide the second `my2` `div`?

E.g.

```
.node2 ? #my2 {
     display:none;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using same `id` for multiple elements is not valid. Assuming you can change the `id` to a `class`, how many such elements would be there in your HTML?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `nth-of-type` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: `.node2 + div { ..` but, obviously get rid of dupe ids ^^

Comment: Like Harry says, you really shouldn't use the same id more than once. They are supposed to be unique. I agree with @ne1410s, nth-of-type would work well in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

***Yes possible:***

> Using `~` you can select all siblings with that class(id your case).

```
.node2 ~ #my2{ 
  display:none; 
}
```

> You can also use **`+`** to select the immediate sibling.

```
.node2 + #my2{ 
   display:none; 
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In order to target the #my2 element after .node2, you'll need to add a + sign between them.

```
.node2 + #my2 {
  display: none;
}
```

But as mentioned before, using multiple id's is invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

this will hide `#my2` which is right after `.node2`

```
.node2 + #my2{
  display:none;
}
```

NOTE: dont use same id for multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

Link each `button` `id` to each `show` `id` IE:  `#button1` links to `#show1`.  Use the `~` selector in your CSS make the association.  Then toggle the `display` between `none` and `block`.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/masterthornton/93zmq4zp/1/)

**HTML**

```
  <a id="button1">Button 1</a>
  <a id="button2">Button 2</a>
  <a id="button3">Button 3</a>

  <div class="text">
    <div class="hidden text" id="show1">This is 1</div>
    <div class="hidden text" id="show2">This is 2</div>
    <div class="hidden text" id="show3">This is 3</div>
  </div>
```

CSS Use the `~` selector to reference each `id`

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#button1:hover ~ .text #show1 {
    display: block;
}

#button2:hover ~ .text #show2{
    display: block;
}

#button3:hover ~ .text #show3{
    display: block
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

NOTE: You could use `<div>` instead of `<a>` for the buttons if you wish.